# Can Adobe Air application turn off self-signed certificate warnings?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, air

Disclaimer: I'm an Air newbie (about 20 minutes in to this experiment).

I have a demo application using Adobe Air that accesses my own SSL web service that uses a self-signed certificate. In .NET clients, I can explicitly handle (and ignore) certificate warnings and suppress them via the ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback. Does anything similar exist in Air? I've examined the URLRequest and URLLoader classes but haven't found anything.

Comment: +1   Great question.  I haven't the foggiest idea what the answer is, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows XP install the untrusted or unknown certificate in your Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. You can i[nstall the certificate from Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-ie8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate) while accessing your site.
There is a [registered bug](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/667971?tstart=1) On Vista and Windows 7. The bug is not resolved yet.

So only solution (without changing server behaviour) is to add your self-signed certificate to system's Trusted Root.

There is additional info about [Secure client sockets](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-1d9a251c124028071fd-8000) in AIR and [SecureSocket class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html).