# Conversion from cert file to pfx file

Tags: security, certificate, pfx

Is it possible to convert a cert file to a pfx file? I tried importing my cerf file into IE, but it is never shown under the "personal" tab, thus I cannot export there.

I am looking for if there is alternatives available.

FYI, the cerf file is created by using "keytool" and then doing an export to a cert file.

Comment: Which IE version are you using?

Comment: @Martin: IE8, on Windows XP platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article describes two ways of creating a .pfx file from a .cer file:

- [Maxime Lamure: Create your own .pfx file for ClickOnce](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/maximelamure/archive/2007/01/24/create-your-own-pfx-file-for-clickonce.aspx)

> Create your public & private Keys (You will be prompt to define the private key’s password):
>
> `makecert.exe -sv MyKey.pvk -n "CN=.NET Ready!!!" MyKey.cer`
>
> Create your PFX file from the public and private key
>
> `pvk2pfx.exe -pvk MyKey.pvk -spc MyKey.cer -pfx MyPFX.pfx -po toto`

Programmaticaly you could do so in C# by writing the byte array directly to a file:

```
byte[] certificateData = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "YourPassword");
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\YourCert.pfx", certificateData);
```

And generally (if you're using IE 8) you might want to have a look at this answer on SO:

- [How to make IE8 trust a self-signed certificate in 20 irritating steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-ie8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/1412118#1412118)

Hope that helps you.