# using IP address instead of Domain name: Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ip-address, ssl-certificate, domain-name

due to a servercrash my IIS settings for a website were lost and I do not have the exact settings in hands. So I replaced the domain name with the ip address, and I am getting this error.

Is there a way to accept the security certificate on IE9 and skip clicking Show Content everytime when I get to the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Certificates are issued to a CN (Common Name) and browsers will complain when the CN doesn't match the address in the browser bar. You need a new certificate issued to the IP address.

Comment: I thought so.. Thank you very much for taking time to respond.. I'll get that done.

Comment: if you only want to fix it for a small group of known users you could try to force IE to accept it like detailed here (for IE8 and "self-signed" certs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I had already tried that. It didnt work. I am pretty sure there is no other way out.. Just wanted to confirm my thoughts if I was wrong...