# Windows Phone 7 not registered certificate center

Tags: windows-phone-7, certificate, webclient

I'm developing WP7 application. It connects by WebClient to secured by certificate https address. Cert is provided by not registered in phone certificate center. When application connect by https no error occurr because cert is not valid - for WP, but really it is. Calling address in browsers says that cert is not valid by any registered CA center. How to register CA center on innstalation process or how install this cert if CA registration is not possible. I can not found anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific): And then email the certificates to yourself (you'll need a physical device). The email app is the only way to install a certificate.

[StackOverflow: What Do I need to do to get... self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific)

Comment: Certificate is not self signed at first. It is from authorized center but it is not in keystore. For example on iOS it is on WP7 not :/ Second thing how I probalby do this if it is an application. Show user to open IE on phone to install cert? There is no automatic possibility?

Comment: The user can't even install it via IE (mobile)! I'm currently facing this same issue with a project - my plan is to create the certs myself, and allow the user to 'email me' to get the certificates. Then, I'll use some sort of vacation responder to automatically send back the certificates for them to install.