# How to bypass Untrusted certificate error from GWT client side code?

Tags: c#, gwt, https, x509

I created a self hosted `HTTPS WCF` web service running on my `Localhost` machine. Now i make a request to this web service from a `GWT` based application hosted on some domain.

I use `self-signed` `X.509`certificate which is not approved yet. Whenever my `GWT` application make requests, It shows an error because of `untrusted Certificate`. Can i bypass this error from my `GWT client` code or suggest me an alternative solutions ?

Is there are any other protocol which supports `WCF` service that we can use for communication and will not trigger the security alert from browser?

### Updated

Whole scenario:

- You installed a `exe` in your system, which take cares of `WCF` web service and importing certificate to your local machine.
- You open a `GWT` based website from your browser. Let's say `some.com`
- `some.com` continuously polling a request to his/her local machine. Let's say on `https://localhost:8098/{someendpoint}`

But because of this `HTTPS` and `untrusted certificate`. It is not able to make request.

Comment: Is the bypass for your local testing or for production?

Comment: @SSR Let's start with local testing

Comment: what does GWT have to do with this? are you saying that you browse to `some.som` and that the resultant page returns html that ends up polling `localhost`? If yes, how is it polling? ajax?

Answer (score 0):

since you said

> Let's start with local testing

How about installing your self signed certificate onto the machine on which you are testing the GWT ?

You should be able to double click the certificate and follow the prompts/wizard to install it.

This applies to development only (for production you'd need a proper certificate)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the scenario. A `GWT` application is hosted on `some.com`. I open that site which is continuously polling  a request on `https://localhost:8083/{some endpoint}`. Each user who are using open `some.com` have to installed a `exe` which all take care of installing the certificate to his/her system  with this `WCF` self hosted web service.
 

It doesn't affect the production environment because everytime web application make request to `localhost`

Comment: @AmitPal then the cert should be trusted. what browser are you using? are you able to trust the certificate via the browser to see if that fixes the issue. (short term then will figure out why browser is not trusting your installed cert)

Comment: `chrome and IE`, how to able to trust the certificate from browser? Are you talking about `Add exception`?

Comment: I tried after adding exception in `Firefox`. It works fine but can i do this without adding exception?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific

if you dont want a manual step then you will need to install the certificate into `Personal->Certificates` on the `Local Computer`

but why do you need https for `localhost` communication? seems pointless

Comment: Because `some.com` is based on 'HTTPS' with approved certificate. So, whenever we call `HTTP` web service from a 'HTTPS' application. It throws an error i.e. `Insecure content want to access and it block the whole web page` :(

I installed the certificate in `Personal->Certificates` on the Local Computer using `MMC`

Comment: is it in 'Local Computer' group? see screenshot i added to my answer