# IIS 7.5 Self Cert - "The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority. "

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

I have followed http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/ and https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html

When I go to the site, it still shows:

> "The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by
>   a trusted certificate authority.
>
> Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or
>   intercept any data you send to the server."

An advice would be most welcome. I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I need to do to get Internet Explorer 8 to accept a self signed certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a self-signed certificate, you need to add the certificate or the root certificate which was used to sign the certificate to your browser.

If this is a public facing website, you may forgot to add the intermediate certificate authority certificates to the web server.  If this is a public facing website, please provide the URL and I can help you more.