# How to Trust a Self-Signed Certificate in IE 11

Tags: ssl-certificate, internet-explorer-11

I get the following error on a website when I try to load content in an iframe from another server in the intranet with a self signed certificate:

> Content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security
>   certificate.

I have tried this already:
[What do I need to do to get Internet Explorer 8 to accept a self signed certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681695/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-get-internet-explorer-8-to-accept-a-self-signed-certific)

But it looks it doesn't work for explorer 11.

Comment: This worked for me with IE 11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2955546/1208379

Answer (score 3):

Those settings should work. You need to check if the certificate being issued is towards localhost or the machine name of your development pc. Check your existing setup by replacing `https://localhost/` with https://{your pc's full domain name}/